# Fast Fourier transform in OpenGL Compute Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, opencl, fft, compute-shader

I'm trying to implement FFT in OpenGL Compute Shaders in educational purposes (that's why I do not want to use CUDA and OpenCL), but I think that some approaches for parallel programming used in OpenCL, for example, are similar to OpenGL Compute Shaders. I've found several code examples of FFT in OpenCL: one of them is [Eric Bainville's article](http://www.bealto.com/gpu-fft_opencl-1.html). Sample source code from it is following:

```
__kernel void fft_radix2(__global const float2 * x,__global float2 * y,int p)

{

  int i = get_global_id(0); // number of threads

  int t = get_global_size(0); // current thread

  int k = i & (p-1); // index in input sequence, in 0..P-1

  x += i; // input offset

  y += (i<<1) - k; // output offset

  float4 u = dft2( (float4)(x[0], mul_1(exp_alpha_1(-M_PI*(float)k/(float)p),x[t]) ));

  y[0] = u.lo;

  y[p] = u.hi;

}
```

Here `x` is input and `y` is output for each step in FFT.
After that, he says that "This kernel must be called for `p = 1`, then `p = 2`, etc. until `p = N/2`. The number of threads at each call is `N/2`, and the work group size WG doesn't matter since all threads are independent." Here `N` is size of input (should be power of 2).
So, my question is about parameter `p`. How can I push that parameter in compute shader, so the latter will be invoked for `p = 1`, then `p = 2`, etc. until `p = N/2`?

Comment: Are you asking how to pass a value to a shader in OpenGL? Because that doesn't change just because it's a compute shader.